# google maps api key not working in facebook iframe application

Tags: php, google-maps-api-2

i have a google map api key which is working in my website but the same api key is not working in my facebook iframe based application showing the error that the api key is not valid and please generate another api key while the api key is same in both places in website and in facebook iframe application..

what problem it may be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article in [GMaps' FAQ](http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/apis/maps/faq.html#keysystem) may be relevant:

> Note that a key for http://www.mygooglemapssite.com/ will only be accepted when the site is accessed using this address.

From similar experiences, I'm guessing that your FB app runs under a different domain name, and thus will need a different API key; or, you may need to generate an API key for your *entire* domain, not just for the page with the map.

To quote the FAQ again:

> For example, if you sign up for a key using http://www.mygooglemapssite.com/, your key is valid for:
>   http://www.mygooglemapssite.com/
>   http://www.mygooglemapssite.com/mysite/
>
> However this key will not be valid for:
>   http://mygooglemapssite.com/
>   http://host1.mygooglemapssite.com/
>   http://host2.mygooglemapssite.com/mysite
>
> If as recommended you request a key for http://mygooglemapssite.com/ your key will be valid for all of the URLs listed above.

There's even a simple troubleshooting step recommended:

> If you are using the Javascript Maps API v2 and your key is not working on your site, put an `alert(window.location.host)` in your code and reload the page. The domain you see in that alert is the one on which your key should be registered.

Comment: yes piskor thank you its done ..this problem solved but now also the map is not showing although i copied and pasted the same code from my website to the facebook iframe application????